# Node Proxy Failing on Login

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I've created a very basic Node Express Proxy server using the http-proxy-middleware module. I'm able to reach the target url which is a login page. However when I try to login to the page I get a '400 Bad Request' error. If I access the same page and enter the same credentials outside of the proxy server I can login without any issue. I would add that after the user logs in they are immediately presented with a page requiring a authorisation (cheeckbox), I'm not sure if this is related to the issue.

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require("morgan");
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
// Create Express Server
const app = express();

// Configuration
const PORT = 3000;
const HOST = "localhost";
const API_SERVICE_URL = "https://##authorisationURL&clientid=####etc>”;
app.use(morgan('dev'));
// Info GET endpoint
app.get('/info', (req, res, next) => {
   res.send('Test');
});
// Proxy endpoints
app.use('/json_placeholder', createProxyMiddleware({
   target: API_SERVICE_URL,
   changeOrigin: true,
   pathRewrite: {
       [`^/json_placeholder`]: '',
   },
}));
// Start the Proxy
app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
   console.log(`Starting Proxy at ${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});
```

**DEBUG EDIT**
Using Morgan set to 'Dev', all I am receiving is the following line:
GET /json_placeholder 302 824 - 798.260 ms
After I login and receive the 'Bad Request' error no further messages appear in the console and when checking the browsers (Chrome) developer tools I receive the following error:
[Bad Request Error Chrome Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oblYm.png)

Comment: You need to debug it first and provide the debugging details so we can help. We will not debug it for you.

Comment: @LinDu hi I'm using Morgan to log the calls to the console but I'm not receiving anything after the user logs in. I've added the line I'm receiving in Morgan and a screenshot of the Developer Tools error.